# What happened between Red Dwarf series VIII and "Back to Earth"?

Tags: continuity, red-dwarf

At the end of series VIII of *Red Dwarf*, "Only the good...";

> The short crimson one is in a pretty dire situation, with everything breaking around them. At one point, Rimmer is approached by Death incarnate, only for Rimmer to kick Death in his presumably skeletal crotch and run, stating "Only the good die young."

This is followed by a placard, saying;

> The end

Which is then replaced by;

> The smeg it is

The next time we see the boys from the Dwarf is in the 3 part "Back to Earth" mini series, where none of this is mentioned.

**What happened to the Red Dwarf and it's inhabitants in between the end of series VIII and the start of "Back to Earth"?**

Comment: In-universe, Series IX happened. This was mentioned in Back To Earth by the DVD salesman.

Comment: @MrLister But that all happened inside a hallucination created by the female Despair Squid.

Comment: @DrRDizzle The DVD salesman was a hallucination; the in-universe events of Series IX, presumably, were not.

Comment: I think there is a slight nod to this in Series X when Rimmer says something along the lines: "Remember when I went to mirror universe and got the cure for the virus, we escaped thanks to...Lister: now it's not the time to relive memories". I'll try to dig up more info later when I have access to the episodes.

Answer (score 5):

**Rimmer:**

Rimmer probably didn't survive.

The Rimmer in Back to Earth is a hologram while the Rimmer who kick Death in the crotch was reconstructed by the nanobots.  Likely Rimmer was brought back as a hologram from a scan from the reconstructed Red Dwarf or from a back up from before Rimmer was reconstructed.

**Kochanski:**

She grew tired of life with Lister and left them.  Kryton witnessed her leaving and claimed she died to spare Lister's feelings.  For much of the time period Lister thought she was dead.

**Holly:**

became waterlogged due to an unavoidable accident and the scutters are trying to dry him out.  He is, therefore, out of commission.

**Lister:**

Caused the unavoidable accident by... leaving the bath running for nine years. Beyond that he appears to have lounged about the ship lazily for years.

**Cat:**

looked fabulous.

**Kryton:**

did chores and seems to have perfected lying.

Unfortunately while I know this is incomplete, I am not aware of much else.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've edited the question slightly since you posted this. While still relevant information, it could do with being reworded to better fit the now larger in scope question of "What happened between series 8 and "Back to Earth?".

Comment: @DrRDizzle well unfortunately I can't answer that well enough as I've never seen season X and my memory of Back to Earth is limited. I'll include in my answer what is obvious. Good Luck.

Comment: Where can one view Red Dwarf or BTE? I loved the series when it was broadcast on PBS but not sure how much of it I saw here in NJ.